# Sequence Layers - How to change time of each picture showing

Tags: after-effects

I applied Sequence Layers/cross dissolve front and back layers to four images. Each image shows for 5 seconds and it seems slow for me, so I'd like each picture to show for 3 seconds - how do I change it with out staring all over again and setting the parameters? Thank you!

I tired moving the time keys and frames manually to change the time of how long the image is showing. But it turns out to be inconsistent

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to speed up a whole timeline is to make a sub-comp by going to your Project panel and dragging your comp to the New Composition button.  Then right-click the comp layer in the Timeline and go to Time > Time Stretch...  Then you can change the Stretch Factor from 100% to 60% to change from 5 seconds each to 3, or you can manually type in the total New Duration you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just realized how to fix it– retime all of your clips first in the timeline by selecting them all and going to the duration column and turning the duration down (ie I had to decrease every image from 10 seconds to 2 seconds).

Sequencing layers retains the duration already set for them. Change the duration before clicking sequence layers and that should work!